# Merge Range upon change in change in column M

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to right code that will merge columns "D" through "L" when the number changes in column "M."

I have the following code, but all it does is merge every row from bottom up to row 2 regardless of value in column "M."

What am I missing???

```
 Sub Merge_Upon_Change()
'Purpose: Merges cells between columns "D" and "L" when column "M" changes

    Dim r As Long, i As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'Turn off windows warning popup

    r = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row            ' find last cell in Column D

        For i = r To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 13).Value <> Cells(i + 13, 13).Value Then   'upon change in column M = 13
                Range("D" & i & ":L" & i).Merge                     'then merge column "D" through "L"

            End If

        Next i

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ''Turn on Windows warning popup

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Cells(i + 13, ...` should be `Cells(i + 1, ...` ?

Comment: Changing the code to `If Cells(i, 13).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 13).Value Then` did the trick.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

*Actually you have already made this question but to pretend this from being unanswered I am posting this answer for any future search about this question.*

When you write your equation as **M i** <> **M i+13** then it simply finds every equation **True** (because probably *i+13 th* row is *not equal* to your *i th* row)  and hereby it merges everything from bottom to the **2nd row** as your **For loop** is until **2**

```
Sub Merge_Upon_Change()
'Purpose: Merges cells between columns "D" and "L" when column "M" changes

    Dim r As Long, i As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'Turn off windows warning popup

    r = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row            ' find last cell in Column D

        For i = r To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 13).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 13).Value Then   'upon change in column M = 13
                Range("D" & i & ":L" & i).Merge                     'then merge column "D" through "L"

            End If

        Next i

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ''Turn on Windows warning popup

End Sub
```

Comment: @XLmatters by the way, I realized that, you have successfully applied that **variable within formula** issue in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Mertinc.  I've been using this sub procedure on a weekly basis without a hiccup since posted Mar 7th.  So it's pretty well tested.